# Sub tilde in LaTeX

Tags: accents, tilde

In LaTeX, `\tilde{x}` puts a ~ on top of the x.
How can I put a ~ below the x?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the command `\utilde` from the [`undertilde`](http://ctan.org/pkg/undertilde) package.

*Added by the crowd:* This package is not part of TeX Live, so you may have to [install it manually](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages). This having been done, using the package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\begin{document}
$\utilde{x}$
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, the \utilde command does not work properly in any sort of multi-line environment -- it inserts too much space between the tilde and the argument.

Comment: @Tristan: What specifically multiline environments?  Like, say, `align`?  I wonder if it's an issue with `\everycr` (which would be weird)?

Comment: It gave extra space in every multiline environment I tried.  I'm not really sure what causes it -- I'm looking into it, but it seems the `\utilde` command really only depends on `\fontdimen5`.  I wonder if that dimension is redefined in a multiline environment....

Comment: I should also add that I'm using the `mathptmx` package

Comment: Looks like in a normal `equation` environment, the original `\baselineskip` is 12pt, while in an `aligned` environment, the original `\baselineskip` is 15pt.  The `\utilde` command uses a `\baselineskip=1pt` command to stack the symbols.

Comment: Ok, found the problem: the `undertilde` package adjusts `\baselineskip` but does nothing to `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip`, which are 3pt and 4pt respectively in a multiline environment, but 0pt and 1pt in a single line environment.

Comment: @Tristan: It seems increasingly as though this package can be duplicated using a two-line `\halign` that sets things up right...

Comment: Just to make my discovery easier to find, I'm going to post and answer it as a question on here, since I can't possibly be the only person who would have experienced this.

Comment: Which is at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62747/undertilde-package-provides-inconsistent-vertical-spacing-between-nucleus-and-ac/62748#62748

Answer (score 3):

Or just copy the 4 lines of code:

```
\def\undertilde#1{\mathord{\vtop{\ialign{##\crcr
$\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr\noalign{\kern1.5pt\nointerlineskip}
$\hfil\tilde{}\hfil$\crcr\noalign{\kern1.5pt}}}}}
```

from

```
undertilde.sty
```

and use the command

```
\undertilde{x}
```

Comment: this will not work for some cases, e.g. \(\mu_{\undertilde{A}}(x)\) will cause A to be printed in full size, rather than scriptsize.