# How to put a tilde under the symbol in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents

It is very easy to put a tilde *over* the symbol in math mode. Simply type `$\tilde{a}$`. But how to put a tilde *under* the symbol in math mode?

Comment: Look at the **accents** package. [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sub tilde in latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/sub-tilde-in-latex)

Comment: The answers can be merged to [Sub tilde in latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/sub-tilde-in-latex)

Answer (score 20):

The [`undertilde` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/undertilde) provides *extensible* tilde accents under elements in math mode via `\utilde{<symbols>}`. Try, for example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\begin{document}
This is $\frac{\utilde{ab}}{c} \neq \frac{ab}{c}$ and so on.
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, as @egreg suggests, the [`accents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accents) provides `\underaccent[<accent>]{<symbol>}`. Try, for example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
This is $\underaccent{\tilde}{\mathcal{A}}$ and so on.
\end{document}
```

See page 2 of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bezos/accents.pdf) in order to extend this using `\widetilde` rather than `\tilde`. It depends on your preference.

Comment: It seems that `\usepackage{under tilde}` is unavailable in TeXLive, only in MiKTeX.

Comment: The solution can be found in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220626/why-is-undertilde-sty-not-found

Answer (score 16):

Using `\underset`:

```
\underset{\sim}{=}
```

...or `\stackrel`:

```
\stackrel{=}{\sim}
```

Answer (score 3):

In 2021, the most convenient way is use the `accents` package

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
This is $\undertilde{\mathcal{A}}$ and so on.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can define a macro:

```
\def\underacc #1/#2{\mathchoice{\uacc\textstyle{#1}{#2}}{\uacc\textstyle{#1}{#2}}
                     {\uacc\scriptstyle{#1}{#2}}{\uacc\scriptscriptstyle{#1}{#2}}}
\def\uacc#1#2#3{\mathop{#2{}}\limits_{#1#3{}}}

%test:
$\underacc a/\tilde, \tilde a$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using «[amssymb](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/amssymb-symbols.pdf)» package we can use macro such as **\lesssim** if we want to place '~' below '<'. Similarly **\eqsim** and **\gtrsim** if we want to place '~' below = or '>'

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) How does this answer the question in general?