# Why is undertilde.sty not found?

Tags: packages, texlive

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\begin{document}
$\utilde{x}$
\end{document}
```

Whenever I am trying to compile it with *Kile*, shows the error:

```
undertilde.sty not found.
```

I have trying to install it from ubuntu14.04(32bit) software centre by searching the name 'undertitle' but there are no such file. How can I  solve this problem?

Comment: You can [download the undertilde package from ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/undertilde). Note that it's 'undertilde', not 'undertitle'.

Answer (score 5):

The package [`undertilde`](http://ctan.org/pkg/undertilde) is marked as having an unclear license. As such, it can't be included in TeX Live (which only includes free software). You will have to download the package from CTAN and install it manually: see [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) for more on this (look in particular at installing a package manually).

Comment: What are the free alternatives?