# how do i write this letter on latex (showed in picture)

Tags: math-mode, equations, vscode

I am trying to write an equation in my thesis, but i have been looking for around 2 hours the way to write this symbol, hope somebody can help me.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23093/237192

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a tilde under the symbol in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23093/how-to-put-a-tilde-under-the-symbol-in-math-mode)

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, using the `accent` package:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\underaccent{\tilde}{\mathcal{A}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]