# How can one draw an Argand diagram of roots in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw an Argand diagram in LaTeX? If you would like an example of the sort of diagram I'd like to draw in LaTeX here is one a DuckDuckGo search found me: http://physicsforidiots.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/5throot6.jpg. The only differences between that and what I want is I want the lines connecting the roots and the origin to be dotted, I would like r and theta not to be shown or labelled and I do not want the colour yellow to appear in the diagram at all. I have seen this related question, [Drawing a circle in the complex plane.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/drawing-a-circle-in-the-complex-plane), but it didn't include any information about labelling points on the circle, or connecting them to the origin.

Comment: What you try so far? Which tools (package) you like to use? At least you should include sketch of desired image in question. The link can become dead after while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution based on `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}%
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-3.5,-3)(6.5,3)
\sansmath $ \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\psset{dash =2.5pt 2pt}
\psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none](0,0)(-3.5,-3)(6.5,3)
\psline[linecolor=white, linewidth=1pt](0,0)(1.43,0)
\pnode(0,0){O}\psdot(6,0) \uput[d](6,0){6}
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\pswedge[linestyle=none, fillcolor=Yellow!40](O){1.43}{0}{72}
\pscircle[fillstyle=none](O){1.43}
\multido{\Iangle=0+72,\i=0+1}{5}{\dotnode[dotstyle=o, dotsize=3.5pt, fillcolor=cyan](1.43;\Iangle){A\i}%
\ncline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesepB=1.5pt]{O}{A\i}}
\pstMarkAngle[linewidth=0.5pt, fillcolor=white, LabelSep=0.55]{A0}{O}{A1}{\theta}
\uput[dr](A0){1.43}
\uput[r](A1){0.44+1.36\mathsf{i}}
\uput[ul](A2){-1.16+0.84\mathsf{i}}
\uput[ul](A3){-1.16-0.84\mathsf{i}}
\uput[dr](A4){0.44-1.36\mathsf{i}}$
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great, although unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me, I get this error from copying the document part of this code and adding the two package lines to the top of my file and building it: https://paste2.org/KsJN0L9L. I get the same error when I just straight copy-paste this all into a new .tex file and build it in TexMaker.

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex`?

Comment: I think so; this is at the top of the log file: https://paste2.org/mkBMsW55.

Comment: Yes, the preloaded fomat is `pdflatex`.  The are several ways to make it work: the old way follows the  `latex-dvips-pstopdf` path.  But you also can compile with `xelatex`. It can also work with `pdflatex` if you load the `auto-pst-pdf` package (*after* pstricks) and compile with the `--enable--write18` option (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX), because pdftex does not have the computing capabilities that are required by postscript, so it has to oursource part of the job. In my opinion,,  the simplest is to use xelatex as a standalone file, then use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Seems like even XeLaTeX has significant limitations here, https://i.imgur.com/HcjUY5B.png.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to say `xelatex` requires the `-shell-escape` switch.

Comment: Hip-hip hooray it works! Thanks!