# Glossary fails to compile with frougon's squiggly underline

Tags: luatex, glossaries

I wish to use the squiggly underline from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532011/21685) answer by [/u/frougon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73317/frougon) together with a glossary. I've saved the following code in a file named `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\math@param}[3]{%
  \fontdimen#3
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont#2
  \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont#2
  \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont#2
  \else\scriptscriptfont#2 \fi\fi\fi
}

\newdimen\@my@yshift
\newcommand*{\myvecBelow}[1]{\mathord{\mathpalette\@myvecBelow{#1}}}

% Squiggly line below the math expression
\newcommand*{\@myvecBelow}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n.base)]
    \node (n) [inner sep=0]
      {\global\@my@yshift=\math@param{#1}{2}{5}%
       \vrule width 0pt height 0pt depth 0.5\@my@yshift\relax
       $\m@th #1#2$};
    % Make sure the snake is always drawn with a little shift below the south
    % border of node n.
    \draw[decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=0.3pt, segment length=2pt}]
      ([yshift=-0.3\@my@yshift]n.south west) --
      ([yshift=-0.3\@my@yshift]n.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{myvecBelow}{name={\ensuremath{x}},description={squiggly underline}}
%\newglossaryentry{myvecBelow}{name={\ensuremath{\myvecBelow{x}}},description={squiggly underline}}
\begin{document}
$\myvecBelow{x}$\glsadd{myvecBelow}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

If I execute the following commands:

```
lualatex test
makeglossaries test
lualatex test
```

they end successfully, and result in the following rendition:

[image: A successful run]

However, if I change the `\newglossaryentry` line to the one that is commented out, the first execution of `lualatex` aborts with the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...

l.36 ...Below{x}}},description={squiggly underline}}
```

Comment: make the definition robust: `\NewDocumentCommand{\@myvecBelow}{mm}{%`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Now I get the following error:
`! Undefined control sequence.

l.18 \NewDocumentCommand

                      {\@myvecBelow}{mm}{%`

Comment: then load the xparse package (or update your tex system, in newer latex xparse is included).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've updated my TeX system and now it works. Thanks!