# Install package undertilde

Tags: installing, tlmgr

I want to install the package undertilde.

When I try to install using method 1 as given in the answer to the question

[How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system/622032?noredirect=1#comment1552817_622032)

i.e. using tlmgr - I get the following errors.

Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home//texmf!

cannot setup TLPDB in /home/****/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.

Comment: if your tex is the linux supplied one not installed directly from tug use your package manage yum or dnf or whatever you use for linux updates

Comment: As David says, sadly the Linux fists cripple tlmgr so it can no longer install packages (their distribution system, their choice). If you're on a Debian/apt based system you can install `apt-file`  and use it to ask Debian which Debian package provides the file `undertilde.sty`

Comment: @daleif if you mean 

apt-file search undertilde.sty

It yields nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, I do not understand. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Well given that CTAN lists that only MikTeX have undertilde (https://ctan.org/pkg/undertilde) that is not a surprise, then it is not available via Linux dists (as they use TeXLive) or via `tlmgr` (for whose using a `tlmgr` that works)

Comment: @daleif So what is the solution?

Comment: If you absolutely need something that has not been updated since 2000!!!! Then you'll need to manually get the `.ins` and `.dtx` from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/undertilde and run latex on the `.ins` file. But I would suggest you look somewhere else for a solution to whatever problem it it you want to use `undertilde` to solve.

Comment: Given that it has not been updated since 2000, there is no guarantee that it will work with modern LaTeX installations.

Comment: Which exactly is your operating system/distribution? (read their documentation, they may have specific instruction to install TeX packages)

Comment: @daleif and David - how does my answer look?

Comment: I would probably have a look at the `accents` package instead.

Comment: @user202729 that does not help when the package is not available for TeXLive

Comment: [accents - Sub tilde in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/sub-tilde-in-latex) // [packages - Why is undertilde.sty not found? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220626/why-is-undertilde-sty-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a bit and with help of comments above, I came to the conclusion that using undertilde package itself is a problem. As @daleif noted that the package has not been updated since 2000. Therefore, the solution is to use some other package to obtain the functionality of the undertilde pacakge.

Specifically, I was using the `\utilde` command from the undertilde package. I was able to do that using `\underset` command. For example, if I needed a tilde beneath r, I will write `\underset{\sim}{r}` to substitute `\utilde{r}`.